# Exceptions (try & catch?)

Tags: c#

I want to restrict values to the variable `anzahlMinen` to numbers from 0 to 24.

How do I do that?
I know exceptions, but I failed doing it.

```
static void Main(string[] args)
    {
      Console.WindowHeight = 23;
      Console.WriteLine("Mit wievielen Bomben möchten Sie spielen?");
      int anzahlMinen = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
```

Comment: What does the code have to do with your description? And what do Exceptions have to do with what you want to do?

Comment: Using exceptions in your case is not a good idea I think.

Comment: @ChruS correct, exception should be thrown only in case of exceptions :) if you can avoid exception, do it

Comment: sorry I pasted the wrong code -.- this one is right

Answer (score 3):

You don't need exceptions for what you want to do:

```
string eingabe = Console.ReadLine();
int anzahlMinen = 0;
if (!Int32.TryParse(eingabe, out anzahlMinen))
    Console.WriteLine("Dies ist keine gültige Zahl!");
else if (anzahlMinen < 0 || anzahlMinen > 24)
    Console.WriteLine("Anzahl Minen muss zwischen 0 und 24 liegen!");
```

**Why you don't need/shoud not use exceptions here:**

Exceptions are used to indicate an unexpected state or error in the program flow. The user entering a non-number or an invalid value is not unexpected and should be handled.

Also, creating and catching exceptions has a huge impact on the performance of your application, so you should avoid throwing exceptions unnecessarily.

Thirdly, exceptions indicate errors and should never *ever* be used as a means to control program flow!

Comment: yah, sorry I took the wrong code :( I have pasted now the right one. Can you please have look on it? Thanks

Comment: The code above is basically what I'm writing, so it should be easy for you to adapt it to your sample.

Answer (score 1):

you can use TryParse, to handle non-numeric values and parse it to int, then check if number is between 0 and 24 and handle wrong numbers in if

```
int i=0;

var isNumber = int.TryParse(eingabe,out i);

if(!isNumber || (i<0 || i>24))
{
   Console.WriteLine("Wrong Number");
   //break or whatever
   //possibly use continue; to go back to first line of while
   continue;
}
```

do not throw exception here, because if you can handle exceptional case without throwing and catching, you shouldn't use try/catch. Try catch is an expensive mechanism and in such simple cases is an overkill.

Comment: As he is obviously a beginner, you should replace the phrase *handle exception* with *handle the error*, so to not confuse him (instance of `Exception` class vs. exceptional condition).